# How can i make Next js Dynamic Route public in clerk.js

Tags: authentication, next.js, clerk

I trying to make nextjs dynamic route  public

```
export default authMiddleware({
      publicRoutes : ['/','/account','/contact','/order','/product/[category]']
});
```

it is giving me error when i am applying it , Please help me, i coudnt find any detail in docs

Answer (score 0):

Try adding "([^/.]*)", so it'll look like '/product/([^/.]*)', that saved me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For the above, write your dynamic routes as such:

```
export default authMiddleware({
      publicRoutes : ['/', '/account', '/contact', '/order', '/product/(.*)']
});
```

The above '/product/(.*)' matches anything after the product route.